# Удалить связанные кортежи в разных таблицах PostgresSQL

Tags: postgresql

Есть 2 таблицы:

```
create table if not exists tasks (
        task_id serial not null,
        author text,
        header text not null,
        description text,
        create_time timestamp,
        primary key (task_id)
);

create table if not exists comments(
        comment_id serial not null,
        content text not null,
        task_id integer not null,
        primary key (comment_id),
        foreign key (task_id) references tasks (task_id)
);
```

Мне надо чтобы когда я удаляю кортеж из таблицы `tasks` все соответсвующие ей записи в `comments` тоже были удалены.

Я пытаюсь сделать это так:

```
delete from comments as c
LEFT inner join tasks as t on c.task_id = t.task_id
where task_id = 1;
```

Но мне падает ошибка синтаксиса в слове `LEFT`. Не понимаю почему...

Помогите пожалуйста создать скрипт попроще чтобы он это делал. Спасибо.

Comment: А вы определитесь какой join вам нужен left или inner - это взаимоисключающие виды. Вообще использовать в delete left очень странно, ведь под него подойдет как записи для которых есть записи во второй таблице, так и все остальные. так что высока вероятность что вы просто удалите все записи в таблице

Comment: А если вам надо что бы записи всегда удалялись автоматически то проще сделать foreign key с опцией on delete cascade

Comment: И кстати есть уж task_id вам заранее известен, то зачем вообще понадобился join. `delete from comments where task_id=1` вполне достаточно что бы удалить все комментарии к задаче 1

Comment: @Mike О! А можно маленький пример? правильно что вместо строчки`foreign key (task_id) references tasks (task_id)` будет `foreign key (task_id) on delete cascade references tasks (task_id)`?

Comment: нет, `foreign key (task_id) references tasks (task_id) on delete cascade` и вы бы документацию на используемую СУБД что ли почитали для разнообразия. там это все указано и заодно облегченный синтаксис есть

Comment: @Mike да смотрел вот тут https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ddl-constraints.html но вот этот облегченный синтаксис меня и сбил, а номального варианта там что-то не вижу.

Comment: @Mike **И кстати есть уж task_id вам заранее известен, то зачем вообще понадобился join. delete from comments where task_id=1 вполне достаточно что бы удалить все комментарии к задаче 1** да но это получится 2 запроса, если я правильно понял что вы предлагаете а хотелось бы все таки одним.

Comment: Да, я сейчас глянул, документация у них не ахти. И в любом случае если сделать в delete join удаление будет только из одной таблицы, сам delete по другому не умеет. если нужно связанное удаление то тогда уже городят конструкции CTE. вот второй ответ тут гляньте http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10145221/how-to-delete-data-from-multiple-tables  но оно громоздко выходит